# Add Gradle to Intellij Project with multiple modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, deployment

Is there an easy way to generate a build.gradle file from and existing project? The solutions I have found to add Gradle to an existing IntelliJ have said to "just add build.gradle to your root directory" but I don't have a build.gradle file. Am I suppose to write this from scratch? My ultimate goal is to use Gradle to generate both a jar and a war for two related applications my structure is as follows:

```
 -Project Root
    -commonFiles
        -src
            -common.java
    -desktopApp
        -src
            -desktopApp.java
        -example.properties   
    -webApp
        -src
            webApp.java
        -web
            -WEB-INF
                -web.xml
            -index.jsp
            -example.properties
```

How would I use gradle to turn these three modules into two deployables? Each of the modules has Maven dependencies and the second two modules are dependent on the first but not on each other.

Where do I start?

Comment: Are you converting it from maven project?

Comment: @PratikAmbani I am new to professional development with IntelliJ. I did not explicitly set up my project as a Maven project but in the IntelliJ>Project Structure menu it allows you to easily download dependencies from Maven

Comment: Can you be sure about whether it is Maven project, if, then it is quite easy to convert it to Gradle project.

Comment: @PratikAmbani What do you mean is it a Maven project? How do I determine this? The structure is defined in a series of .iml files not via a POM.xml

Comment: If you can provide your project structure.

Comment: I don't think it is a Maven project. Would it be easier to make it a Maven project first and then convert it? That seems like a roundabout way to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138874/discussion-between-pratik-ambani-and-brian-mikey-halbert).

Comment: There is no automated way to do it, you have to write `build.gradle` files manually.